# i want to favorite images from recycler view using Sql databse problem is that when i click on favorite button the table is creat but data not store

Tags: java, android

**DATBASE**
this is my AddImage function in databse where i m addindimages..

```
  public long addImage(Photos_model model) {

        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cvImage = new ContentValues();
        cvImage.put(NAME, model.getName());
        cvImage.put(URL, model.getUrl());
        cvImage.put(FAV_ID, model.getImageID());

       return db.insert(FAVORITE_TB ,null,cvImage);

    }`
```

This is my adapter class where i m calling addimges function by clicking fvrt button

```
favoriteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            Photos_model model=new Photos_model();
            DBHelper dbHelper=new DBHelper(context);
            long  result = dbHelper.addImage(model);

            if (result>0){
                Toast.makeText(context,"data save"+result,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show();


            }else {
                Toast.makeText(context,"data failed"+result,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(context,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have instantiated the model

```
Photos_model model=new Photos_model();
```

But you haven't added any values to that model in your onclick()

So before

```
long  result = dbHelper.addImage(model);
```

set the values for your model

```
model.setImageID(val)
....
```